# How can I optimally wrap around an alphabet position shifting?

Tags: c++, encoding

I'm writing a beginner program that first inputs an integer *n* and then a word (all capital) and shifts each letter by *n* positions in the alphabet. I have the shifting part down (see code below) but I'm struggling to wrap it around so it starts at beginning of alphabet once it goes past Z. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
string output = "";
string str;
cin >> str;
    for (char c : str) {
        c = c + n; 
        output = output + c;
    }
cout << output << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be the easiest to understand:

Move the input character into the range [0,25]

```
(c - A_idx)
```

add the offset

```
(c - A_idx) + n
```

get the modulo of the offset (wraps it around)

```
(c - A_idx) + n) % Letters
```

Map it back into the range expected by ascii

```
((c - A_idx) + n) % Letters + A_idx
```

Complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string output = "";
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    const auto A_idx = 65;
    const auto Z_idx = 90;
    const auto Letters = Z_idx - A_idx + 1;// 26 maybe?
    for (char c : str) {
        c = ((c - A_idx) + n) % Letters + A_idx;
        output = output + c;
    }
    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small tidbit: instead of having `65` and `90` you can simply use `'A'` and `'Z'`

Comment: I understand your comment on cheating on homework, but in all fairness I didn't ask for a complete code, just how to wrap around the alphabet so I can figure out how to apply it to my task. Honestly, this is how one learns new functions. Thanks for the answer, I see see creating a defined index and looping it is better than my idea (if statements), I'll play around with it a bit and see if I can make it work.

Comment: On the contrary, I thought it was a well asked question (which I upvoted after small edits) with a clear question and an attempt

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this, so it all comes down to what is most readable. Personally, I'd have something like this:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::string word = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (auto& c : word)
{
    c += n;
    if (c > 'Z')
        c -= 26;
}
std::cout << word;
```

It simply increments `c`, and if `c` goes greater than `'Z'` it minuses the number of letters in the alphabet (which should be obvious to anyone).

You could also instead pre-check if it were to go over `'Z'`, and if so minus the value instead, with something like:

```
if (c + n> 'Z')
    c += (n - 26);
else
    c += n;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are innumerable ways to do it, and for that reason, questions like this generally get closed. There is no right answer, and the suggestions just go on and on. The quickest way to fix your version is to add a check for wrap-around at each iteration of the loop.  It's near optimal, particularly since you're only doing one string. But optimization is silly here. The calculations will be some millions or billions of times faster than reading in the strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    string output;
    for (char c : str) {
        c = c + n; 
        if (c > 'Z') c -= 26;  // One added line.
        output = output + c;
    }
    cout << output << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```